# Error Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation (MethodBase.Invoke Method)

Tags: c#, exception, reflection, invoke

I want to catch the exceptions that are thrown in methods called with invoke method because I am getting an error Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

```
 string[] results = (string[]) SendMethod.Invoke(Slave, parameters);
```

Comment: Catch that invocation exception and then check the inner exception.